# Safely timeout ReadLine on a network stream

Tags: c#, timeout, tcpclient

How can I safely timeout the following code?

```
var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 6000);
new StreamReader(client.GetStream()).ReadLine(); // close the client if no line arrives after 5 seconds...
```

Previously I had a timer running on another thread which called client.Close() if the timeout expired, but I don't think calling `client.Close()` like that is thread-safe?

Comment: Why not to use TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin `ReceiveTimeout` property.